# Transcendental element in extended field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. $$k(t) = \{ f(t)/g(t) \mid f(x), g(x) \in k[x], g(x)\neq0 \}$$ be an extension over $k$.
I wanna prove that, for any $m(t)$ in $k(t)\setminus k$, $m(t)$ is transcendental in $k$, i.e. If there exist an $f(x)$ in $k[x]$ so that $$f(m(t)) = 0$$ holds in $k(t)$, then $f$ must be 0 polynomial, namely $$f(x) = 0.$$

---

I think $k(t)$ over $k$ is a very important example for field extension. 
Write $$m(t) = g(t)/h(t).$$ I think it ok to add that $$gcd(g, h) = 1,$$ and $h$ is monic. Then I thought it difficult to conclude from $$f(g(t)/h(t)) = 0$$ that $$f = 0.$$ So I am wondering if there is some good approach.
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: You can write $f(g(t)/h(t))$ in the form $Q(t)/h(t)^n$, where $Q(t)\in k[t]$ and $n$ is the degree of $f$. Examine the numerator $Q(t)$. You see that there is only a single term that isn't obviously divisible by $h(t)$. But the value is zero, so even that term has to be divisible by $h(t)$ ($k[t]$ has unique factorization). What can you conclude?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Smoothly work out that way!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(m(t))=0$ where $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$. Then,
\begin{align}
0&=h(t)^nf(m(t))=h(t)^nf(g(t)/h(t))\\
0&=h(t)^n\left(a_n\frac{g(t)^n}{h(t)^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{g(t)^{n-1}}{h(t)^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_1\frac{g(t)}{h(t)}+a_0\right)\\
0&=a_ng(t)^n+a_{n-1}g(t)^{n-1}h(t)+\cdots+a_1g(t)h(t)^{n-1}+a_0h(t)^n
\end{align}
Therefore, $t$ is algebraic.

Comment: Well, I think the last line is to be continued. As you have written, h(t) have to divide g(t)^n, so this may contradict with gcd(g, h)=1. So we must have h=u*1, where u is a unit. But h is monic, so h=1. Then m=g be a polynomial. Then it is easy to show that f=0, which means m is transcendental. Do you think so?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you have to argue a bit that the RHS of the last line is not identically 0.

Comment: Suppose the polynomial is identically $0$. One can assume $g$ and $h$ are coprime and that $a_n\ne0$ and $n$ minimal, so also $a_0\ne0$. If $h$ has an irreducible factor, we get a contradiction; so $h$ is constant. If $g$ has an irreducible factor, we get another contradiction.